# ImportError: No module named 'psutil'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, odoo-11

Hello i'm trying to run an odoo project and everytime i try to run it i get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named 'psutil'
```

i have tried to run

```
import psutil
```

via command line and it gives me also this error 
i'm using `odoo 11` and `python 3.5`
i have tried the following commands to install the package

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

also

```
sudo apt-get install python3-psutil
```

and for sure

```
sudo pip3 install psutil
```

and it supposed to be installed now as when i run the last command again it gives me this message

```
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (5.4.5)
```

but when i run the odoo project it gives me the error

thanks

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by "run an odoo project"? How do you invoke Python?

Comment: i cloned the project from the repo and run the following command 
./odoo.py

Comment: Did you check https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/install.html#running-odoo and the following section on virtualenvs?

Comment: yes i have but i'm cloning another project from the companie's repo

Comment: Can you describe your Python setup in more detail? Are you using anaconda or virtualenv?

Comment: iam using virtualenv, and actually this is my first time with odoo xD

Comment: Are you sure that psutils is available in your virtualenv? How did you set up your virtualenv?

Comment: i installed virtaulvenv via the command line 
sudo apt-get install -y git virtualenv
and i don't know if psutils is available or not how to check for it ?

Comment: Check out http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the same problem (I am working on a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04), but I was getting a similar frustrating message around `psutil`. The problem seemed to be that it was installed in my Python 2.7 version, and `pip` was only looking at that version, seemingly ignoring the fact that my current virtual environment was Python 3.5.

I noticed `pip3` did nothing, so I installed `pip3` with `apt-get install python3-pip`. Then I could could successfully use `pip3 install psutil` to install into the correct Python3.5 and my virtual directory.

What I am puzzled by is how I got so far without hitting this earlier. I have installed lots of things over the last few months with `pip` and they seemingly went into both versions (side-by-side Python2.7 and Python3.5 environments for running TensorFlow). Why is it different for `psutil`?

But it works now.

Perhaps these steps might fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Python3 default version in Ubuntu

From the comment:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Will show you an error:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

You need to update your `update-alternatives`, then you will be able to set your default python version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

Then run :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Set `python3.6` as default.

Or use the following command to set python3.6 as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
```